# OBS Studio Virtual Camera Button Missing in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, camera, obs-studio

I started OBS Studio 27.2.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. The virtual camera button does not appear, though it did in 20.04.

I have tried:

- Help > Check For Updates (I'm on the latest version and that menu option doesn't appear anyway)
- purging and reinstalling from the ppa.
- disabling Secure Boot (it was already disabled).
- installing v4l-utils, v4l2loopback-utils, v4l2loopback-dkms.
- restarting after each of these steps

In case this is somehow relevant, OBS isn't following my system theme, using light theme when the system is set to dark. That's not the issue I'm looking to solve here, though.

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks but I'm already using the deb